# GIT working directory in htdocs (using Eclipse Luna in Mac)

Tags: php, eclipse, macos, git, xampp

I created a php project (beta) in Eclipse Luna and started working on development. The folders and files are in place in htdocs [htdocs/beta].

Now I need to version the project using GIT. I am the only person working in this project and so I would like the htdocs/beta to be the working folder for GIT. When i tried using the wizard to create repository, GIT placed the files in its own preferred directory. The trouble is to test the changes, i need to place the files to htdocs every time which is affecting the development time.

I was wondering if there is a way to set htdocs/beta as the working directory? In this way, I can develop, test and subsequently commit with no hassles.

Environmnet is XAMPP in MAC

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: any help on this matter is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you will need to change the `DocumentRoot` value in httpd.conf That file is an Apache config file that defines how your local web server will operate and react. There is a `ServerRoot` setting that tells where the root directory for xampp resides, and this should not change and can stay default. The DocumentRoot tag tells which directory should be served up by the apache webserver when a client connects. Set this value to your working directory, ie. your git repository.

In your working directory, when you make local code changes, you can instantly refresh your localhost browsing session and see the changes you've made.